# Using newData on Updates in Firebase Security Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm having issues using newData within Firebase security rules when doing a update operation.

Here is my data structure:

[image]

And here are my rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "videos": {
        "$videoId": {
            "data": {
                "content": {
                    "srcURL": {
                        ".write": "root.child('videos/' + $videoId + '/tokens/' + newData.child('/videos/-1vidid/requestToken').val() + '/read' ).exists()"
                    },
                },
                "meta": {
                    "status": {
                        ".write": "root.child('videos/' + $videoId + '/tokens/testTok/read').exists()"
                    }
                }
            },
            "requestToken": {
                ".write": true,
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is data I'm trying to write via update:

```
 {
  "videos/-1vidid/data/meta/status": "uploaded", 
  "videos/-1vidid/data/content/srcURL": "https",
  "videos/-1vidid/requestToken": "testTok"
  }
```

And here are my rules failing when I try to use newData;

[image]

Notice it's working when I hardcode in the token ("testTok"), but when I try and use newData it won't clear.

Here are more attempts when I get rid of the "videos" and $videoId ("-1vidid) from the newData childs:

[image]

[image]

Any idea why newData does not appear to be working on updates?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the rules.

Comment: Added more information

Comment: Your rules are difficult to read.  The indentation is inconsistent, and it's hard to tell where the curly braces line up.

Comment: Are the simulation results screenshots (which include the passed and failed rules) not easier to read?

Comment: Without rules to see (with line numbers), the screenshots don't mean very much.  Rules can span multiple lines, and without context, it's not possible to say what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Also, in general, screenshots are difficult to read, and it's preferable to leave plain text where it's available.

Comment: Fixed my braces, is that better? The rules are working fine when I hard code the value in but when I use newData they are wrong. Thanks for the help and advice

Comment: I passed your rules JSON through https://beautifier.io/, and pasted it back into the question. Please use a tool like that yourself next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relevant rules:

```
root.child('videos/' + $videoId + '/tokens/' + newData.child('/videos/-1vidid/requestToken').val() + '/read' ).exists()"
```

The `newData` variable refers to the new data **at the current location**. There is no child `/videos` under the location where you've defined the rule.

I assume you want to start reading from the root. In that case you can either use `root`, which gives you the existing data at the root, or use `newData.parent().parent()...` (repeated for however many levels up you need to go) for getting the updated data.

Comment: That was it, fixed!